# Why I am getting the error "This post does not meet our quality standards."?

Tags: support

I wanted to ask a question but not able to submit it due to the error "This post does not meet our quality standards.".

Can anyone help me on what are these quality standards?

Comment: Refer [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074)

Comment: @TheDestroyer "If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit on our network." question was brief but couldn't be looked up in a dictionary :) Anyway is there any minimum character limit?

Comment: There is a minimum character limit for asking questions. Also, if you get that message, don't go to circumvent it by adding superfluous text. It will contribute a lot towards question bans. (Mentioning in general).

Comment: Any idea, what is that minimum character/word limit?

Comment: 30 characters.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCHnN.png